# Magento export product gives error: "Fatal error Call to a member function getName() on a non-object"

Tags: php, magento, export, magento-1.9

I'm try to export product from magento admin end & getting below error:

```
Call to a member function getName() on a non-object in /home/projectname/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Entity/Product.php on line 171
```

And also gives the error in the firebug console:

```
NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://domain.com/index.php/admin/export/getFilter/key/a1f090de71262ab853875ebe91411165/entity/catalog_product?isAjax=true
```

[image]

How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

Before this try please try to do re-index data and check again.

The issue is $structure[$i] that is entity_id (category id) passing in this function. It seems entity_id is not a valid in catalog_category_entity or category flat tables.

Check in your database if your flat tables are fine.

**Alternative but a not a good solution.**

**Open :** /home/projectname/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Entity/Product.php
**Find:**

```
 $path[] = $collection->getItemById($structure[$i])->getName();
```

Replace this with

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($structure[$i]);
$path[] = $category->getName();
```

**Note:** Before posting any new question, please search for the answers (To avoid duplicate questions)
**Check this link:** [Same Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/85174/problem-export-product-no-valid-data-sent)

Comment: I've tried to find but didn't get these question. thanks for notify me